# Segmentation fault while using "ifstream"

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ifstream

I'm trying to get a part of text in a file.
I used "ifstream":

```
#include <fstream>

void func(){
    char *myString;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("/proc/cpuinfo");

    while (infile >> myString){
        if  (!strcmp(myString,"MHz"))
        break;
    }
}
```

and I get a "Segmentation fault". does anyone know why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not allocated memory for the `myString`. Use `std::string`. Or better any other language, python, perl, or unix utils such as grep, awk, sed.

Answer (score 2):

Because the target value should be:

```
std::string myString;
```

and not `char*`.  It's possible to use `char*`, but you have to ensure that it points to something big enough first.  (In your case, it doesn't point anywhere—you forgot to initialize it.)  And defining “big enough” is non-trivial, given that you don't know the size of the next word until you've read it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason why C++ has a string class, you know. It's because using char pointers is cumbersome and error-prone.

```
infile >> myString
```

will read from the file into *wherever `myString` points to. And it is an uninitialized pointer, it points to some random garbage address.

If you absolutely *do* want to use char pointers instead of strings, you'll have to allocate a buffer you can read data into.

But the sane solution is to replace it entirely by `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not allocate memory for `myString`. The quick solution to this is to use `std::string` instead of the C-style `char*` strings, which does memory management so you don't have to.

Here's why your error occurs:

When you declare `char *myString` you are creating a pointer to a character. However you do not initialize this pointer to anything, so it can point absolutely anywhere in memory. When you do `infile >> myString` you are going to write a bunch of characters at an unspecified location in memory. It just so happens that this location was a vital part of your program, which caused it to crash.

Answer (score 0):

`char myString[256]` compiles fine just as well too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


 void func()
 {
    char myString[256] ;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("/proc/cpuinfo");

    while ( ! infile.eof() )
    {
          infile >> myString;
          cout<<myString<<" \n"; 

        if  (! strcmp(myString,"MHz") )
        {
            infile.close();
            break;
        }
    }
     infile.close();
     cout<<" \n";  
}

int main()
{

    func();
    return 0;
}
```